# MysqlConnect.net 8.1.0 no figura en el origen de datos de Visual Studio 2022 al intentar crear TableAdapter C# MariaDB

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mariadb

A alquien le ha pasado que no figura el MysqlConnect.net 8.1.0 en el origen de datos de Visual studio 2022 ? Para conectarce con Mariadb, un saludo yvgravias de antemano.